# Is it standard procedure for vets to check if a cat is pregnant before spaying?

Tags: cats, desexing

Before cats are spayed, owners can choose to have blood-work done to see if the cat can undergo anesthesia. During this blood-work, do veterinarians usually check for the hormone (hCG?) indicating whether the cat is pregnant?

In other words: **Is it standard procedure for veterinarians to check if a cat is pregnant before spaying her?**

Comment: Generally. If you are spaying a cat, the kittens if any would be unwanted anyway... I suspect this is a question you don't really want to ask. If it matters to _you_, you could have a hormone test done on your cat before spaying...

Comment: @keshlam There could be risks to it, especially if the pregnancy is far along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not, though we would question it if she looked pregnant (late pregnancy) and may opt to wait until she has her kittens before spaying. Not all veterinarians are comfortable aborting kittens when they are almost fully developed.

Comment: Is there a blood (or urine?) test to determine if the cat is pregnant if it's not so clear?

Comment: Yes there is a blood test where we check the progesterone levels in their body.